# solution : Manage space between group columns in highchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, resolve

[image]I was working with highchart on group columns , well here I had to reduce the size of column but by doing this highchart weirdly managing space between columns when data is less, so I was searching for solution where I found bellow link which is realy helpfull

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/77

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the space by using `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` properties:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    pointPadding: 0.1,
    groupPadding: 0.3
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4875/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.groupPadding

Comment: definitely it will work with this scenario  , but it will work with columns spacing weirdly after giving pointWidth:15 or fixed width

Comment: In this case you need to use `pointPlacement` property: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4877/